# Using awk to read from one file and inject properties into another file

Tags: awk

I have a property file which includes hundreds of lines like the following `mainfile.txt`:

```
del.frequencyMinutes = 360
del.gracePeriodMinutes = 4320
vol.operationsEnabled = true
vol.multiFolderContainer = false
pool.capacity.differential = 30
pool.cpu.differential = 30
vol.single.pool.maxVolSize = 100
vol.multi.pool.maxVoluSize = 20
```

And I want to have a small file where I want to keep some changes depending on some different test setups like the following `change.txt`:

```
del.frequencyMinutes = 1440
del.gracePeriodMinutes = 2000
```

When properties (field `$1`) in `change.txt` is matched those in mainfile then their value should be overwritten into mainfile.  I tried the following code but missing some important things:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{val1=$1;val2=$2;next}{ if ($1==val1) printf $1" = "val2;else if ($1 != val1) print $0}' changes.txt mainfile.txt
```

I saw that it only injected second property row in `change.txt` into `mainfile.txt` while missing first one. So,

1. how could I add all `change.txt` rows
2. The code above only prints the results, not write into mainfile, so how could I permanently write into mainfile?

I'm not very good in awk/shell scripting so I would appreciate your explaining things what I did wrong here

Comment: How to replace a file with the output from Awk is separately a very common FAQ; please search before asking. GNU Awk has `-i inplace`, or you can write to a temporary file and then rename it.

Comment: As side note: you seems to be using `printf` without justified cause (`printf` with single argument does output string *without* trailing output row separator, which by default is newline), GNU AWK manual has chapter dealing with [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf.html)

Comment: Exactly, if printf used then formatting should be added, unnecessary there. Unless I use it with something like printf("%s %s", $1, $2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=" = "}NR==FNR{arr[$1]=$2;next}($1 in arr){$2=arr[$1]}{print}' changes.txt mainfile.txt
```

which for `changes.txt`

```
del.frequencyMinutes = 1440
del.gracePeriodMinutes = 2000
```

and `mainfile.txt`

```
del.frequencyMinutes = 360
del.gracePeriodMinutes = 4320
vol.operationsEnabled = true
vol.multiFolderContainer = false
pool.capacity.differential = 30
pool.cpu.differential = 30
vol.single.pool.maxVolSize = 100
vol.multi.pool.maxVoluSize = 20
```

gives output

```
del.frequencyMinutes = 1440
del.gracePeriodMinutes = 2000
vol.operationsEnabled = true
vol.multiFolderContainer = false
pool.capacity.differential = 30
pool.cpu.differential = 30
vol.single.pool.maxVolSize = 100
vol.multi.pool.maxVoluSize = 20
```

Explanation: I set both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`) to `=`, so after altering one field line would still be `property = value`, then when processing first file (`NR==FNR`) I set array `arr` value for key property to be its' value. `next` is used so no other action is undertaken. In all but first file: if property (1st field, `$1`) is one of `arr` keys, then set value (2nd field, `$2`) to be value for that key, always `print` whole line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Your answer is virtually identical to mine, and doesn't use any GNU Awk facilities (though the `-i inplace` extension would have been useful)

Comment: I must point following differences: I am storing values only rather than whole lines in array, I also exploit `OFS` and I also trigger line rebuilding when such need arise.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the previous values of `val1` and `val2` when there is more than one line in the input file. The usual and very common solution is to read the lines into an associative array.

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR { a[$1] = $0; next }
  $1 in a { print a[$1]; next } 1' changes.txt mainfile.txt >temp
mv temp mainfile.txt
```

This prints the input from `changes.txt` when it sees a first field which was in that file, and otherwise prints the original input line. The results are written to a temporary file, which we then rename to move it back on top of the original `mainfile.txt`.

The `-F =` is dubious here; perhaps take it out, and/or normalize whitespace around `$1` before checking if it's in `a`. String comparisons in Awk (or pretty much every general-purpose programming language) regards strings as different if they have different amounts of spaces around the text.

The lone `1` at the end is a common Awk shorthand for "if you got this far, just print the current input line."

Comment: Thank you your solution also worked and yes those whitespaces in string comparison could cause issues if whitespace around "=" not used in some cases..